# Deleting blank rows from a csv file and saving it using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a csv file with 40031 rows. I have to delete all the blank rows in the file. here i'hve written some PHP code for row 13 to row 40, but it's not working. where is the problem?

My PHP Code:

```
<?php 
function del_blank_row($filename, $startrow, $endrow){
    $status = 0;
    //check if file exists
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        //end execution for invalid startrow or endrow
        if ($startrow < 0 || $endrow < 0 || $startrow > 0 && $endrow > 0 && $startrow > $endrow) {
            die('Invalid startrow or endrow value');
        }
        $updatedcsv = array();
        $count = 0;
        //open file to read contents
        $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
        //get file contents in an array
        $csvcontents = fgetcsv($fp);
        //for every row
        foreach ($csvcontents as $csvcontent) {
            if (!empty($csvcontent)) {
                array_push($updatedcsv, $csvcontent);
                continue;
            }
        }
        print_r($updatedcsv);
        $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
        fputcsv($fp, $updatedcsv);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        die('File does not exist');
    }
}

//-----call-----//
$csvdata=del_blank_row('h.csv', 13, 48);
```

Comment: fgetcsv() only reads one line at a time. You would need to use it in a loop. Check the examples on the docs: php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: you need also to put parentheses around your conditions and make sure that `||` and `&&` are clearly distinguished

Comment: With 40.000+ lines you may reach PHP's memory limit. If that happens please search for an answer before creating a new question.

Comment: Just as a side note, if this isn't some part of a larger problem consider using an existing tool. eg. this sed 1 liner might do the job: `sed -i '13,48 { /^$/d; }' h.csv` (back up the file first :))

Answer (score 0):

First Close the file in its read mode and then open in the write mode!
That is put a `fclose($fp);` statement before `$fp = fopen($filename, "w");`